# R my S4 vector won't index correctly in data.table

Tags: r, vector, indexing, data.table, r-s4

I'm trying to treat my own S4 class as a vector in a data.table. Everything works smoothly, except that when I index rows in the data.table, my indexing method is not applied to the vector. This works perfectly with a data.frame, but not a data.table.

Here is my class:

```
setClass('myvector', contains = 'vector', slots = c(foo = 'logical')
```

It contains a vector, and has a parallel logical vector 'foo' in one slot. 
I make a `[` method so that the foo slot is indexed along with the contained vector.

```
setMethod('[', 'myvector', 
          function(x, i) {
            new('myvector', x@.Data[i], foo = x@foo[i])
          })
```

If I put this class into a `data.frame`, everything works smoothly.

```
mydf <- data.frame(Numbers = new('myvector', 1:26, foo = rep(TRUE, 26)),
                   Letters = new('myvector', letters, foo = rep(FALSE, 26)))
```

I can index rows of the data.frame, and each of my `myvector` objects gets indexed correctly using my `[` method. You can see, that after `mydf[1:10, ]`, the `@foo` slot within the `$Numbers` vector has been indexed.

```
mydf[1:10, ]
mydf[1:10, ]$Numbers@foo
```

However, if I try the same thing with `data.table`, the contained vectors get indexed right, but `@foo` doesn't get indexed.

```
library(data.table)
mydt <- data.table(Numbers = new('myvector', 1:26, foo = rep(TRUE, 26)),
                   Letters = new('myvector', letters, foo = rep(FALSE, 26)))

mydt[1:10, ]
mydt[1:10, ]$Numbers@foo
```

It seems that the default `[.vector` method is applied within the `data.table`, instead of my specific `myvector` `[` method. Interestingly, the `@foo` slot doesn't disappear, and the `Numbers` and `Letters` vectors each retain their class, it's simply that `@foo` doesn't get indexed.

Does data.table always use it's own built-in vector indexing or something? Is there anything I can do to convince `data.table` to use my `[` method?

Comment: the `data.table` package does create a lot of methods for `[` and `[<-` and these use nonstandard evaluation rules. You are likely to have to write specific methods for `[` with signature `data.table, myvector` yourself, which overwrite them (though they might later call the `package:data.table` methods to include their functionality)